# Jenkins pipeline complex Git checkout

Tags: git, jenkins

When I'm starting a new project, normally I'll do something like
git clone some-git-url
then git checkout  if needed.

When Jenkins does it, I see these somewhat more elaborate steps:

```
using credential bluecost_git
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git
 > git init /home/bcjenkins/Taas_Jenkins/workspace/cirrus-ssc-cost-file-sender/cirrus-ssc-file-sender # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials CostProject (dpydalsprd101.sl.bluecloud.mycompany.com, /home/bluecost/.ssh )
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials CostProject (dpydalsprd101.sl.bluecloud.mycompany.com, /home/bluecost/.ssh )
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.mycompany.com:IC2E-SPRINT/cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
```

My pipeline has this git snippet step:

```
    def GIT_NAMES = 'cirrus-ssc-file-sender.git'
    def GIT_URL = 'git@github.mycompany.com:MYPROJ/'
    env.GIT = 'git@github.mycompany.com:MYPROJ'
    def SERVICE_NAME = 'ssc-file-sender'
    env.BRANCH_NAME = SERVICE_NAME
    env.BRANCH = BRANCH_NAME

    git url: "${env.GIT}/cirrus-ssc-file-sender", branch: "${env.BRANCH}", credentialsId: "${env.GIT_CRED}"
```

Then when something goes wrong, I get a message like:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

Can someone explain why Jenkins does this in a convoluted way?

Note: I previously wanted to know why I got the "could not find revision" message. I found through comparison that the plugin, does not like the url to end in .git, even though the URL in the .git/config remote origin parameter does. I hope that tip helps someone.

Comment: Often I had a similiar problem, so I used to enable for each new pipeline the "Jenkins Pipeline Wipe Out Workspace" step.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca I can sincerely appreciate that sometimes.